# Delisting a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a public Chrome extension that I now want to hide from public view, while still retaining the users.

If I change the visibility settings on a Chrome extension from 'Public' to 'Unlisted', will the current users still continue to see it as normal, as well as receive updates if I push any out in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the visibility settings as "Unlisted", then the extension will not be listed in search and gallery, but everyone with a direct link can install, and current users will receive all future updates.

For more information, you can check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/distribute-web-app).

Comment: Note: the linked documentation is only slightly relevant, but there's no better source than this or the publishing form itself.